# detect spaces in front or behind the word for highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight

I would like to know how I can give highlight on any letter and if there is a space after or before the word it doesn't eat the space...

```js
function highlight(text) {
  const InputsTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.item-question-faq');


  for (const inputText of InputsTexts) {
    let innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
    let index = innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase());


    if (index !== -1) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + '</span>' + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
  }
}

document.body.onload = function() { highlight('order'); };
```

```css
.item-question-faq {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p  class="item-question-faq webrep-faq" >the order is important</p>
```

[image]

Here is a printout of how it looks when applying the highlight[image]

the application can't use Jquery or libraries
how can i solve this?

Comment: hello! welcome to stack overflow. this question is more likely to receive a helpful answer if you isolate the problematic behavior in a self-contained, standalone example. please take a look at [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some helpful tips.

Comment: for instance, if i try to isolate your javascript into a standalone example ([like this](https://jsfiddle.net/xfwsbzcn/)), i don't see the spaces getting eaten -- which suggests the problem may lie in your CSS rather than in your javascript.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow  htm and css available in the question

Answer (score 2):

This is because you've set the parent element (paragraph) to `display: flex`. Part of what a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) does is decide how to pack in the children elements, and how much space to add between them.

It is almost certainly a mistake to use `display: flex` for an element that directly contains raw text. Usually, flexboxes are wrapper elements that contain discrete blocks of content.

If you remove this property, allowing the paragraph to use its native `display: block` mode, the spaces will be preserved as you expected.

```js
function highlight(text) {
  const InputsTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.item-question-faq');


  for (const inputText of InputsTexts) {
    let innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
    let index = innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase());


    if (index !== -1) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + '</span>' + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
  }
}

document.body.onload = function() { highlight('order'); };
```

```css
.item-question-faq {
  margin-left: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p  class="item-question-faq webrep-faq" >the order is important</p>
```

---

minor tip: you can use javascript's [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to make your code just a little more concise.

Instead of:

```
const InputsTexts = document.querySelectorAll('.item-question-faq');
for (const inputText of InputsTexts) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Consider:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item-question-faq').forEach((inputText) => {
  /* do stuff */
});
```

Comment: very very good man, thanks u